# Is there a O(n) way to find the most repeated item in list without using counter

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I need a solution that is O(n) for finding most repeated element in a list.
If 2 or more numbers are repeated the same amount of time return smallest number.

```
from collections import Counter
 
def most_frequent(n):
    count_occurence = Counter(n)
    return count_occurence.most_common(1)[0][0]

input = [2,4,4,5,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,1]
```

Output should be 4 which should give the count of 3

Comment: You can define your own `counter` function then, which is  straightforward. But why not using Counter? If it's learning assignment, let's try first?

Comment: Please edit your own attempt to solve this problem without using Counter into your question.

Comment: `Counter` doesn't do anything fancy: it's a subclass of `dict`, and it initializes itself by iterating over its input and updating an internal count of how many times it's seen the current element.

Comment: @DanielHao I had a solution with binary search but that unfounfortunately uses sorting and the algorithm is not O(n) anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `max` and `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def most_frequent(li):
    maxes=[]
    for k,g in groupby(sorted(li)):
        maxes.append((len(list(g)), -k))
        
    return -max(maxes)[1]
```

Or use a dict as a counter:

```
def most_frequent(li):
    cnt={}
    for e in li:
        cnt[-e]=cnt.get(-e, 0)+1
    
    return -max(cnt.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))[0]
```

Or if your data has runs of similar numbers, without the O(n log n) sort step you can combine these two methods:

```
def most_frequent(li):
    cnt={}
    for k,g in groupby(li):
        cnt[-k]=cnt.get(-k,0)+len(list(g))
        
    return -max(cnt.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))[0]
```

And it likely is the case that using `max` on a comprehension is faster than using a lambda:

```
def most_frequent(li):
    cnt={}
    for k,g in groupby(li):
        cnt[-k]=cnt.get(-k,0)+len(list(g))
                
    return -max(((y,x) for x,y in cnt.items()))[1]
```

In all cases, you are construction a tuple of `(-element_in_list, count_of_that_element)`:

```
cnt=[(-2, 2), (-4, 3), (-5, 2), (-3, 2), (-6, 3), (-1, 1)]
```

You then take that `max` of that by reversing the tuple either with a comprehension of a key function. Your answer then is `-element_in_list` since it was negated to take the `max`.

Comment: I checked how much time each run took  with timeit module and by far the first one was the fastest, and after that comes the one without the groupby where only dictionary was used as a count, anyway I didn't do major tests just some basic tests with given list.
I really appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: Doesn't surprise me at all. BUT it depends on a lot. Big O only describes the relationship between processing a small number of items vs a large number. It says nothing about absolute relative speed x vs y on the same number of items.

Comment: Be sure to try `-max(((y,x) for x,y in cnt.items()))[1]` because that is likely faster than `-max(cnt.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))[0]`